# After/When/If you go to the gym for 2 years, you will get fit and stronger - the differences?

Tags: meaning

**Example 1:**

> After you go to the gym for 2 years, you "will" get fit and stronger

**Example 2:**

> When you go to the gym for 2 years, you "will" get fit and stronger.

**Example 3:**

> If you go to the gym for 2 years, you "will" get fit and stronger.

Examples 1-3 are three general statements.

I think they are quite similar in meaning.

However, I still wonder whether there are subtle differences.

**So, my questions are:**

**Question 1**

Are Examples 1-3 all correct?

**Question 2**

Can the "will" be omitted?

**Question 3**

What are the differences between the 3 examples?

Comment: Surely the process of getting fitter and stronger is a gradual one; you won't suddenly change once the magic milestone of two years has been achieved! If you must mention a timescale, I think it would be more idiomatic to say _After/when you have been going to the gym for two years..._

Comment: @KateBunting Oh I got it. The examples are grammatically correct, but the meanings are bit off. If there is a magic milestone, then my examples are acceptable. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: I feel it would be more natural to say "If you go to the gym regularly, you will start to get fitter and stronger" OR "When you have been going to the gym for [period of time], you will be much fitter and stronger".